# NextJS - Link to shortened url

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want the profile url to be '/p/username' but I still want the folder in pages to be 'Profile'. When I try this:

```
<Link href="/profile/[username]" as={`/p/${user.username}`} >
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: The provided `as` value is incompatible with the `href` value
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to access the file in `/pages/Profile` folder from `/p/slug` URL, can use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in your `next.config.js` to access:

```js
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/p/:slug*",
        destination: "/Profile/:slug*",
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

And for your link, since Next.js 9.5.3, you can do directly:

```js
<Link href={`/p/${encodeURIComponent(user.username)}`} >
```

cf. [Link documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)